# `make -f Makefile.in` fails around @SET_MAKE@ and @SHELL@

Tags: makefile, automake

I'm trying to compile transmission from source code checkout from svn, and ran into some issues compiling.

It says

> "Makefile.in:15 *** missing seperator..."

where the line was `@SET_MAKE@` that has no white spaces in front of it.

After I commented out that line, it says:

> make: @SHELL@: Command not found
>   Makefile.in:484: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make: *** [all-recursive] Error 127

The Makefile.in is generated by `./autogen.sh`

Automake and Autoconf are both up-to-date and exceeds minimum requirement.
Debian Jessie updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Makefile.in` is only a **template** for a makefile, this is typically used by `GNU Autotools`. In order to generate a Makefile from that template, you have to run `./configure`, which should also have been generated by `./autogen.sh`.

Comment: It turned out there was an error after running ./autogen.sh that I didn't see. After I corrected the error it generated a regular Makefile